# Data visualization for small web projects

Tags: website-design, info-visualisation, design-process, methodology

What's an example of good data visualization for a small web projects?

I don't want to overwhelm the client. I must track progress, and keep stakeholders engaged.

What I've got so far

```
PERCENT OF TIME (front-end, 20hrs)
Logo/Brand Management 25%
Usability 25%
Refactoring/Changes 25%
Development 25%
```

Comment: does the client care about any of those specifics? I'm guessing, no. I'd focus on whatever you need to get things done internally and only communicate what involves the client directly (do they need to provide branding guidelines? When do they need revision requests submitted by? Etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for but maybe something from http://flowingdata.com/2008/09/09/winner-of-the-personal-visualization-project-is/ will help you? Having all 4 of those at 25% is not really correct, unless your client is really picky you should be spending roughly 40% developing and 10% changing. If you are changing as much as you are developing, you'll run into issues when payment time comes around, because that's a very big key that their management is bad.

Comment: It would all depend on what we mean by 'development' and the particular process their team is using for it.

Comment: Refactoring/changes can be 25% if there is design and development involved. I need to work that differently.